# Dropbox api v2 for Android: how to get media files details?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

How to get media files and their details with Dropbox API v2 for Android(Java)? I have gone through the [documentation](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/FileMetadata.html) for the `FileMetadata` , but I couldn't find the methods to get file details like file type(e.g. music, video, photo, text, ...) , file's URL and thumbnail.

this is my folders and files list Asyntask:

```
        //login
        DbxClientV2 client = DropboxClient.getClient(accessToken);

        // Get files and folder metadata from root directory
        String path = "";
        TreeMap<String, Metadata> children = new TreeMap<>();
        try {
            try {
                result = client.files().listFolder(path);
                arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                //arrayList.add("/");
                while (true) {
                    int i = 0;
                    for (Metadata md : result.getEntries()) {

                        if (md instanceof DeletedMetadata) {
                            children.remove(md.getPathLower());
                        } else {
                            String fileOrFolder = md.getPathLower();
                            children.put(fileOrFolder, md);

                       //if (!fileOrFolder.contains("."))//is a file
                            arrayList.add(fileOrFolder);

                            if (md instanceof FileMetadata) {
                                FileMetadata file = (FileMetadata) md;

                                //I need something like file.mineType, file.url, file.thumbnail
                                file.getParentSharedFolderId();
                                file.getName();
                                file.getPathLower();
                                file.getPathDisplay();
                                file.getClientModified();
                                file.getServerModified();
                                file.getSize();//in bytes
                                MediaInfo mInfo = file.getMediaInfo();//Additional information if the file is a photo or video, null if not present
                                MediaInfo.Tag tag;
                                if (mInfo != null) {
                                    tag = mInfo.tag();}
                            }
                        }
                        i++;
                    }

                    if (!result.getHasMore()) break;

                    try {
                        result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());//what is this for ?
                    } catch (ListFolderContinueErrorException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (ListFolderErrorException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (DbxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want media information, you should use [`listFolderBuilder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#listFolderBuilder-java.lang.String-) to get a [`ListFolderBuilder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/ListFolderBuilder.html) object. You can use call [`.withIncludeMediaInfo(true)`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/ListFolderBuilder.html#withIncludeMediaInfo-java.lang.Boolean-) to set the parameter for media information, and then [`.start()`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/ListFolderBuilder.html#start--) to make the API call. The results will then have the media information set, where available.

Dropbox API v2 doesn't offer mime types, but you can keep your own file extension to mime type mapping as desired.

To get an existing link for a file, use [`listSharedLinks`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#listSharedLinks--). To create a new one, use [`createSharedLinkWithSettings`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#createSharedLinkWithSettings-java.lang.String-).

To get a thumbnail for a file, use [`getThumbnail`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#getThumbnail-java.lang.String-).

Comment: thanks a lot! is there a file url method other than `listSharedLinks` ? which should be equivalent to `api.media(entry.path, true).url` in API v1... I need the media url to stream to TV, it is something like `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/b5c1234gu6dwk5f/mango.jpg` for an image

Comment: The equivalent of v1's `media` would be [`getTemporaryLink`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#getTemporaryLink-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Thanks! I found `GetTemporaryLinkResult` class after upgraded from 2.0.1 to latest 2.0.6 API